# Gridview custom Album item

Tags: android, gridview

i am making an gallery window in android i am trying to achieve something like that my first square will show my first item of gallery and below that is empty square like in this screenshot how can i achieve this please help 
[image]

this is my current xml file for single item in gridview i am showing simple square but how to draw white square below like in above image

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_add_messages"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.***.****.views.SquarImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/img"
            android:alpha="0.8"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/darkColor"
            android:baselineAligned="false">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/label"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="jahsjasjjhjhj"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="12"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/options"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_settings"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Sorry for my previous answer . Checkout this one

**1.Create a new xml file in drawable folder name it , test.xml .**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#CABBBBBB" />
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**2.Create a layout xml file and paste below code . Add necessary resources as your own.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#eee"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/test"
            android:layout_height="200dp">
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:background="@drawable/test"
            android:layout_height="200dp">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/test_image"/>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="#a4252525"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_height="70dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="4"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="My Pictures"
                            android:textSize="8pt"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:textColor="#FFF"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="1"
                            android:textSize="8pt"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

                            android:textColor="#FFF"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/test_icon"

                            />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**3. Below is the screenshot for this code view :**[image]

Hope this is helpfull for you.

Comment: but its a circler imageView i need like square as i mentioned above :(

Comment: thats exactly i was looking for thanks mate stay blessed :)

Comment: Welcome , Happy Coding :)